# How to manually start a service without having a controlling terminal?

Tags: terminal, command-line

I maintain an application that runs as a background service, started either on boot as a StartupItem or manually from the command line. I want to know how to launch it manually without having a controlling terminal, or completely detach after launching.

Using TextEdit to illustrate, I know that if it's launched from Terminal, it blocks the prompt until the program is quit, and will close if the terminal window is closed.

```
/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit
```

Both can be avoided by adding `nohup` and `&` to the command, respectively:

```
nohup /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit &
```

Or `disown` can be used instead of `nohup`:

```
/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit & disown $!
```

Although TextEdit will stay running if the terminal window is closed, a warning will still be thrown. This is because TextEdit still has a controlling terminal, as indicated by `ps -ax`:

```
$ ps -ax | grep TextEdit
28390 ttys003    0:00.12 /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit
```

It's not until the terminal window is closed that TextEdit finally is TTY-free.

```
$ ps -ax | grep TextEdit
28390 ??         0:00.12 /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit
```

I know it's possible to start the service without a controlling terminal with direct system calls, because when the StartupItem is used to start the service (either on boot or with SystemStarter), it starts without a TTY. My question is, can this also be accomplished using just the command line?